# Why is count(column_name) behaving like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

Consider the relation account (customer, balance) where customer is a primary key and there are no null values.

I would like to rank customers according to decreasing balance. (The customer with the largest balance gets rank 1. Ties are not broke but ranks are skipped: if exactly two customers have the largest balance they each get rank 1 and rank 2 is not assigned.)

Why does the following query never prints the customer having rank 1?

```
    select A.customer, 1+count(B.customer) 
    from account A, account B 
    where A.balance < B.balance 
    group by A.customer
```

[SQLfiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7e62/2)

Comment: Because there are zero other customers with a balance less than the customer with rank 1, so there are no rows that satisfy the join condition.

Comment: So, `count(B.customer)` takes a null set in that case. But why `1+count(B.customer)` does not return 1?

Comment: Because there are zero rows in the B table to join with the 'top ranked account' in the A table, so the addition never happens, and the COUNT never gets to count 0.  If you had an OUTER join, you might be in with a fighting chance, but you're using an old-style inner join (which is another no-no — they went out of fashion in the last millennium).

Comment: Ok. So, `count(null set)` returns `null`. Right? and then `1+null` is not possible. Is that so?

Comment: You don't have a null set.  You simply don't have a row for the top-ranked account because no row satisfies the join condition.  And COUNT(null set) returns 0, just for a change.  Forget the rank calculation.  Just run the query without the `, 1 + COUNT(B.Customer)` part.  Note that the highest ranked entry does not appear.

Comment: What is `count` returning in this case (as you said it is not returning 0)?

Comment: For which case?  For the case where A.Balance is the maximum, the join returns no row, so the count is not executed.  And actually I said that COUNT(null set) returns 0 -- the opposite of what you said I said.

Comment: Ok! Got what you are saying by removing `, 1 + COUNT(B.Customer)`.

Comment: @RajarshiSarkar If either of the examples helped you, could you please mark one as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7e62/23)

**Ranking without skipping a rank**

```
set @number:=0;
set @balance:=0;

select customer, balance, rank 
from (
  select 
    *, 
    @number:=if(@balance=balance, @number, @number+1) as rank,
    @balance:=balance
  from account
  order by balance
) as rankeddata;
```

**Result**

```
customer balance rank
S        300     1
Q        400     2
R        400     2
P        500     3
```

To show ranking from 500 -> 300, just change the `ORDER BY balance` to `ORDER BY balance DESC`

**Skip rank if multiple rows have same rank**

If you prefer to skip an assigned rank, you can tweak the query a little bit [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e076/1).

```
set @number:=0;
set @balance:=0;
set @rank_reused:=0;

select customer, balance, rank
from (
  select 
    *, 
    @number:=if(@balance=balance, @number, @number+1+@rank_reused) as rank,
    @rank_reused:=if(@balance=balance, @rank_reused+1, 0) as reused,
    @balance:=balance
  from account
  order by balance desc
) as rankeddata;
```

**Result**

```
customer balance rank
S        300     1
Q        400     2
R        400     2
P        500     4
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the count.

You are doing a join between A and B and show only the records where A.balance < B.balance since there is no such record for your top rank customer (by definition there is no account with higher balance) you don't get any record.

This should do the trick

```
select A.customer, ( 
    select count(*) + 1 
    from account B
    where A.balance < B.balance
) from account A
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement will give you a rank of all customers based on their balance:

```
SELECT A.customer, A.balance, ( 
    SELECT count(*)+1 
    FROM account B
    WHERE A.balance < B.balance
  ) AS rank
FROM account A ORDER BY A.balance DESC
```

The result will be:

```
customer balance rank
P   500 1 
Q   400 2 
R   400 2 
S   300 4
```

`order by A.balance` does the ordering, while `desc` ranks from largest to smallest. Lastly, the subquery provides the rank (note the +1).

Here's an the example [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7e62/24).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select A.customer, 
(select count(*) from account) -
(select count(*) from account a1 where a1.balance<a.balance) rank
from account A
Order by rank
```